# Find/replace limited to one column but many worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'll start by saying the only VBA I know is trial and error from manipulating recorded macros. I am a CPA trying to learn VBA the hard way (and wishing I had gone to school for computer programming instead!).

I have large workbooks with multiple worksheets. Cells highlighted yellow in column G need to be formatted in a specific way in order for the file to import correctly to a web-based program. They need to remain highlighted yellow, be right/bottom aligned, and custom format of mm/dd/yyyy. I recorded a macro doing find/replace to try to replace all yellow highlighted cells within column G with highlighted yellow, bottom/right justified, custom format mm/dd/yyyy, but it's not limiting the replace to only column G. I also have no clue how to get the macro to loop through all the worksheets before finishing. Help?!

This is what I have from my basic macro recording:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Range("G:G").Activate
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    With Application.ReplaceFormat
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
        .Subscript = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
End Sub
```

EDITED POST TO ADD: Please see screenshot of a typical sheet I am trying to reformat. Again, I only need to worry about changing the formatting on cells that are yellow highlighted, but I'm still having trouble limiting the find/replace to column G only... [1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRu30.jpg]

Comment: If you are trying to make sense of recorded code, the first thing to do is get rid of all the extraneous, verbose code that was added but doesn't do anything,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make sense of recorded code, the first thing to do is get rid of all the extraneous, verbose code that was added but doesn't do anything. Recorded code covers all aspects of an operation whether you require them or not.

This is a rewrite of your original using only what is required.

```
Sub yellowSpecialReplace()
    Dim w As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .Interior.Color = 65535
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(w).Columns("G:G")
                .Cells.Replace What:=vbNullString, Replacement:=vbNullString, _
                               LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
            End With
        Next w
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code works, but it changes ALL cells that are highlighted yellow to the new formatting. I am still trying to limit the find/replace to column G and haven't been successful. To workaround, I have created a second macro that will correct the formatting in some of the other specific cells, but I am having the same problem with column H, which needs different formatting only applied to col H. I am attempting to edit my post to add a screenshot of the sheet to make my dilemma clearer...

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that seems to do what you describe.  I've placed a lot of `.select` statements in the code so that you can learn how it works by stepping through it, but you should remove all those once you understand. Also, I have some commented out code at the bottom which you can use to loop through multiple sheets. The animated gif shows the code running on an example I made up.  Let me know if you have questions.

```
Sub reformat()
Dim sh As Worksheet, r As Range, cell As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set r = sh.Range("G1")
  r.Select
  If r.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then Set r = sh.Range(r, r.End(xlDown))
  r.Select
  For Each cell In r
    With cell
      .Select
      If .Interior.Color = 65535 Then
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
      End If
    End With
  Next
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'place the above code in this loop if you want
'to apply the above to all worksheets in the workbook
'also remove the set sh=ActiveSheet line
Next sh
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get the code to work, but I'm thinking it's due to user error and not because the code is incorrect. I copy/pasted directly as written and I don't think that is what you intended for me to do. I am just starting to read more materials on coding and to say I'm a beginner is an understatement!

Comment: Don't give up. I did intend that you would copy/paste the code so that you would have something that worked as a starting point. I just confirmed that it does work by doing the following: 1) open a new workbook, 2) pasted the above code into a new module, 3) put in sample dates in column G, formatted differently with some having the default yellow, and then 4) stepped through the code. It worked just as shown. I suggest that you step through the code and make sure it's doing what is shown in the animation above. For example, is the code getting inside the If statement of the For..Next loop?

Comment: After following your steps, I figured out why it wasn't working at first. I failed to mention my data doesn't start in G1. Once I changed the starting cell for the range it is working perfectly. The only step that isn't working is the 'For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets'. While stepping through, the command is highlighted but just continues on to Next  sh and End sub despite my sample worksheet having multiple tabs with the same layout. Am I supposed to move that code to another location in the module? I've tried removing "Set sh = ActiveSheet" and then get errors.

Comment: Yes, "place the above code in this loop" means that all the code above needs to go inside the For...Next loop except the line you mentioned which should be removed entirely. I'm happy you're being helped, and I hope you'll try to spend some time to consider how the code works. This thread has become long (which SO discourages) so perhaps anything else can appear as a new question.

Comment: Thank you! I am learning from the steps and I started reading “Excel VBA for Dummies” today :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Cycle through each worksheet in the active workbook then AutoFilter on the cell color then apply the changes to the visible cells..

```
sub yellowSpecial()
    dim w as long

    with activeworkbook
        for w=1 to .worksheets.count
            with worksheets(w)
                if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
                with .range(.cells(1, "G"), .cells(.rows.count, "G").end(xlup))
                    .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=vbyellow, operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                    with .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1,0)
                        if cbool(application.subtotal(103,.cells)) then
                            with .specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)
                                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                                .numberformat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                            end with
                        end if
                    end with
                end with
                if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
            end with
        next w
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: Do you think you're missing an `End If` with `if cbool(application.subtotal(103,.cells)) then`

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I typed it as `end with`.

Comment: I unfortunately can't use a filter on my workbook due to the way the data is arranged. Thank you for your response though!